# Scilab sort by second column

Tags: sorting, matrix, scilab

I have some data:

```
P = [3 10 25 32 43 1 3
6 12 35 39 49 4 9
2 9 23 36 47 2 9
...
7 20 35 42 44 3 7
15 18 19 41 42 4 6
10 18 32 35 46 3 10];
```

Data is always between 1 and 50.
I am selecting left 5 columns and 2 right columns:

```
L=P(:,1:5);
R=P(:,6:7);
```

I am counting occurrences:

```
a=tabul(L);
b=tabul(R);
```

In this moment, in `a` I am getting:

```
50.   3.
49.   4.
48.   3.
```

which tells me, that value 50 occurs 3 times, 49 occurs 4 times and so on.
What I need now is sort matrix `a` by second column but the first column should be arranged with the second column values. So it would look like this:

```
49.   4.
50.   3.
48.   3.
```

How can I sort matrix `a` this way (later I will sort `b` the same way)?

I was trying something like:

```
[a,idx]=gsort(a(:,2),"g","d");
a=a(idx,:);
```

but this not does what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are overwriting `a` in the `gsort` call although you just need the index here. The following does what you want:

```
[dummy,idx]=gsort(a(:,2),"g","d");
a=a(idx,:);
```